# Copy a file to HTTP Server through C program

Tags: c, curl

```
< HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
```

even i am using POSt in curl API, it is saying that PUT method is not allowd.

> ```
> < Date: Fri, 20 May 2016 11:03:06 GMT
> * Server Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) is not blacklisted
> < Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
> < Allow: GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS,TRACE
> < Content-Length: 318
> < Connection: close
> < Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
> ```

getting above error,while i am trying to use HTTP POST. below is the code that i am trying

```
  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    /* upload to this place */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_HTTP | CURLPROTO_HTTPS);
    /* tell it to "upload" to the URL */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);

//    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, NULL);

    /* set where to read from */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, fd);

    /* and give the size of the upload (optional) */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE_LARGE,
                     (curl_off_t)file_info.st_size);

    /* enable verbose for easier tracing */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */
    if(res != CURLE_OK) {
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    }
}
```

Comment: do i need curl installed on the server running http ?

Comment: @Michael do you have any idea ?

Comment: Have you read cURL documentation? Especially the `HTTP POSTing` section of https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html Seems you miss some things in your code

Answer (score 0):

Leave just CURLOPT_POST and remove CURLOPT_UPLOAD. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010346/should-i-set-curlopt-upload-when-i-post-file-with-curl-in-php).

It seems that libcURL does something internally when you set CURLOPT_UPLOAD that "locks" the PUT method to the handle, as noticed in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410869/libcurl-post-after-put-issue), making the following curl_easy_setopt with CURLOPT_POST ineffective.